# Deserializing a nested JSON string, cannot access properties

Tags: c#, json

I am having issues deserializing a nested JSON array from the Genius lyric website API. I formulated the object using http://json2csharp.com. When I deserialize the object, I am unable to access the properties inside of the class, which wasn't entirely unexpected, I am just not sure how to properly design an actual solution to the problem. The JSON object conversions work fine when they are not nested.

What would be the best way to go about handling this?

Here is the conversion code:

```
string test = await G.SearchGeniusASync(textBox1.Text);

var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GeniusApiObject>(test);
```

Here is my class:

```
class GeniusApiObject
{
    public class Meta
    {
        public int status { get; set; }
    }

    public class Stats
    {
        public bool hot { get; set; }
        public int unreviewed_annotations { get; set; }
        public int concurrents { get; set; }
        public int pageviews { get; set; }
    }

    public class PrimaryArtist
    {
        public string api_path { get; set; }
        public string header_image_url { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string image_url { get; set; }
        public bool is_meme_verified { get; set; }
        public bool is_verified { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public int iq { get; set; }
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public int annotation_count { get; set; }
        public string api_path { get; set; }
        public string full_title { get; set; }
        public string header_image_thumbnail_url { get; set; }
        public string header_image_url { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int lyrics_owner_id { get; set; }
        public string lyrics_state { get; set; }
        public string path { get; set; }
        public int? pyongs_count { get; set; }
        public string song_art_image_thumbnail_url { get; set; }
        public Stats stats { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string title_with_featured { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public PrimaryArtist primary_artist { get; set; }
    }

    public class Hit
    {
        public List<object> highlights { get; set; }
        public string index { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public Result result { get; set; }
    }

    public class Response
    {
        public List<Hit> hits { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public Meta meta { get; set; }
        public Response response { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the source for the SearchGeniusASync method in case it is helpful:

```
public async Task<string>SearchGeniusASync(string searchParameter)
{
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", clientAccessToken);

    var result = await httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri("https://api.genius.com/search?q=" + searchParameter), HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead);
    var data = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    return data;
}
```

This is the scope I am given access to:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BvgG.png

Here's a sample JSON request in plaintext:

https://pastebin.com/iA8dQafW

Comment: Do not link to your JSON, add a minimal complete sample to your question.

Comment: Your `GeniousApiObject` doesn't have any properties, just nested classes, so that is why you don't see anything.

Comment: @maccettura The accessibility of `GeniusApiObject` does not affect it. Changing it to public yields the same issue.

Comment: @maccettura `GeniousApiObject` is not private.

Comment: @RonBeyer Could you explain to me the proper way to format a nested JSON object in the example I've shown? I haven't found any concise documentation that describes my exact issue.

Comment: Those classes do not match the code that json2csharp or jsonutils or Visual Studio generates

Comment: @TomFarley Try `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GeniusApiObject.RootObject>(test);`

Comment: @Plutonix It does? I just tried it again and it's the same format.

Comment: @RonBeyer `GeniusApiObject` is internal, sorry.  Forgot the default access modifier.  But what you said (classes not properties, deserializing to the right class) was right, I misread the code

Comment: @RonBeyer The data inside the nested classes are all null when I try to do that.

Comment: @TomFarley we still need you to update the question to include the JSON sample, you are expected to include a [MCVE]

Comment: @TomFarley I just pasted your code and what I wrote, works perfectly fine on my end. [Here is a screenshot of it working](https://imgur.com/a/bK0ZO2j)

Comment: I can confirm it works fine for me too

Comment: @TomFarley basically `GeniusApiObject` is useless and you can remove it.  Then change your code to: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(test);` and you will be fine.

Comment: @TomFarley This question is getting out of control . I believe there is a problem with expectations here.  I saw one thing, some other guy saw a different thing.  The root cause is the expected result is missing from your question.  My best GUESS is that you expect ALL classes to be saturated.  And  Some other guy guessed that you only want 2 which are defined in RootObject.  In that case the problem is the data itself. It only defines 2 "classes" that's why u only see 2.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey I am confused to what you are seeing.  The JSON object is pretty straight forward.  At the root it has "meta" and "response".  Where are you seeing a divergence from what we are all saying and what you are seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GeniusApiObject` is not needed in the code, but I'll leave it in just because it helps organize things (may be that something else also has a `RootObject` from the auto-generator).

The problem is that you are trying to deserialize to what is just an empty class, the class itself has no properties, so you can't deserialize to it. You need to deserialize to the `GeniusApiObject.RootObject`.

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GeniusApiObject.RootObject>(test);
```

Will deserialize to the `.RootObject` subclass. This is verified working:

[image]

Where I'm using `File.ReadAllText("test.json")` to load the example API data provided.

[Here is a .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZWexGh) showing it working (without the root object and only one song in the response). Thanks to [@maccttura](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2457029/maccettura).

Comment: The problem is you are assuming he only wants `GeniusApiObject.RootObject` to be saturated.  I see the data he posted, which only saturates those two yes.  But I don't think the OP desires that outcome.  Thus the confusion.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey there is nothing else to populate based on that JSON.  What are you referring to?

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey If you read the object tree, the other sub-classes are used, so it will use them all. The root JSON doesn't use anything else...

Comment: @RonBeyer I had my own answer primed if you weren't going to post.  I have a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FRPjNG) prepped if you would rather use that instead of your screenshot

Comment: Well good luck then.  I'm dropping off this question because it's unclear what is desired.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey I am not trying to be a jerk, I am curious if we are missing something.  I would love for you to explain your concerns so we are making the right call as a group

Comment: @maccettura I'll add it, but had to modify it a little since it was printing off "meta" instead of the status code.

Comment: @RonBeyer just fixed that and added a namespace too (preferable to an empty class container)

Comment: All I'm saying is just ignore the JSON for a second.  What's odd is the placement of RootObject.  I am guessing the OP wants the RootObject to be `GeniusApiObject` and NOT another nested class.  It's a strange setup.  I would expect a serialization to occur at the root level (geniusApiobject) not in some sub class.  The generated code did some weird stuff.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey It's strange because it was generated by a tool that can't make assumptions. Using Visual Studio's "Paste JSON As Classes" [results in a similar structure, without the `GeniusApiObject` container](https://pastebin.com/NZERQ9ik). Rename `Rootobject` in that case to `GeniusApiObject` and you would be there...

Comment: This is the answer. My problem was a fundamental misunderstanding on how the JSON data was organized. I understand now. Thanks to @maccettura and Ron and others for their help